# What is the notation for the max element over two 2D matricies (images)

Tags: notation

I have two images which contain scalar values, let's call them $X$ and $Y$.  They are each of size $h \times w$.  How do I compactly write the maximum scalar of the two matrices?

My initial thought is the following:

$\max\limits_{ i,j,k,l}  ( \mathbf{X}_{ijkl} \vert  \mathbf{Y}_{kl})$

Comment: If you use MATLAB, you may use https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html#:~:text=M%20%3D%20max(%20A%20)%20returns,maximum%20value%20of%20each%20column.

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't a programming question but a notation question for a manuscript. Thanks anyways though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\max\left(\max_{i,j} X_{i,j}, \max_{i,j} Y_{i,j}\right)$$